# How to pass values according to selectred node in jstree

Tags: javascript, html, ajax, node.js, jstree

I have jstree in my web page, and I want to change the items in the web page according to the node selected in the tree.

I started with an example to view an image for each selected node.
Here is the HTML code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Tree Monitoring</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <script src="/assets/navbar.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jstree/3.2.1/themes/default/style.min.css" />
  </head>

  <body>
    <% include partials/nav.ejs %>
    <div class="container" style="padding-top: 100px;">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-lg-12">
            <div id="mytree1">
          <ul>
                    <li>element1
                    <ul>
                        <li>element2
                            <ul>
                    <li>element3</li>
                            </ul>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>

            <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
            <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jstree/3.2.1/jstree.min.js"></script>
            <script>
                $(function () {
                // 6 create an instance when the DOM is ready
                $('#mytree1').jstree({
              //"plugins": ["checkbox"]
            });
            $('#mytree1')
              // listen for event
              .on('changed.jstree', function (e, data) {
                var i, j, r = [];
                for(i = 0, j = data.selected.length; i < j; i++) {
                  r.push(data.instance.get_node(data.selected[i]).text);
                }
                console.log(r[0])
              })
              // create the instance
              .jstree();
            });
        </script>
            </div>
        </div>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-lg-12">
        <!-- Conditionally display Sign In or Sign Out -->
        <% if(r[0]=="element1"){ %>
          <img src="/assets/image1.png" class="img-responsive center-block">
        <% }%>
        <% if(r[0]=="element2"){ %>
          <img src="/assets/image2.png" class="img-responsive center-block">
        <% }%>
        <% if(r[0]=="element3"){ %>
          <img src="/assets/image3.png" class="img-responsive center-block">
        <% }%>
      </div>
     </div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

I keep having the error: r is not defined.

How can I send the variable r from AJAX to JS? Is there a simple way to make the web page dynamically change its content according to selected node?

Thanks,,

Comment: I think the confusion when you have ` var i, j, r = [];` that happen on client side (javascript) and it exists on the `client browser` only. But when you use `<% if(r[0]=="element1"){ %>` you are looking for a variable called `r` server side (which according to the error you don't have it defined anywhere). The option would be to move the display logic to the client side. If this is something your requirements can allow, I can help you with that.

Comment: @DavidEspino, I do prefer doing most of the logic in the server side as most of the variables are there, but I will really appreciate if you help me to move this particular case to client side

Comment: Is there a way that you can match this property `data.selected[i]).text` to be the `src` of the image?

Comment: I do not know actually, I used the image as an example, the real case has charts and maps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't see any ajax in your code.

To dynamically change your image on a node click, I would assign the image an id and update its `src` attribute in the part where you get the selected node as below.

Check out demo - [Fiddle Demo](https://fiddle.jshell.net/ermakovnikolay/0gpbtf9h/)

```
...

for(i = 0, j = data.selected.length; i < j; i++) {
     r.push(data.instance.get_node(data.selected[i]).text.trim());  
     // notice the trim above - you need it since the label will have a line break symbol, which you don't need
     // I would rather get an id of the node, than the label
}


var src = '';
switch (r[0]) {
    case 'element1':
        src = '...';
        break;
    case 'element2':
        src = '...';
        break;
    case 'element3':
        src = '...';
        break;
}
$('#img-status').attr('src', src);
```

Comment: Exactly what I needed, Thanks a lot